# How to retrieve HTTPS json data using QNetworkRequest

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, https, windows-7, qt5.5

I have some code that successfully retrieves json content from an HTTP source:

```
void MainWindow::Test()
{
    QNetworkRequest request;
    QString filename = "http://ip.jsontest.com";
    //QString filename = "https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos";

    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/json");
    request.setSslConfiguration(QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration());
    request.setUrl(QUrl(filename));

    QJsonObject json;
    QNetworkAccessManager nam;
    QNetworkReply *reply = nam.post(request, QJsonDocument(json).toJson());
    while(!reply->isFinished())
    {
        qApp->processEvents();
    }

    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        QByteArray response_data = reply->readAll();
        QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(response_data);
        QJsonObject object = document.object();
        qDebug() << "Json File Loaded : " << filename;
        qDebug() << "IP: " << object["ip"].toString();
    }
    else // something went wrong
    {
        qDebug() << "Json File Failed to Load : " << filename;
        qDebug() << "Error : " << reply->errorString();
    }

    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

However, when I change the URL to the HTTPS one (the line commented out in the code) I get the error **"server replied: Not Found"**

The HTTPS url works fine in a browser.

In my search for answers I found many different suggestions but no actual working solution.

I believe the problem is down to QT not supporting SSL 'out of the box' due to licensing issues, but here's what I've attempted so far.

I installed "Win32OpenSSL-1_0_2h.exe"
I then copied "libeay32.dll" and "ssleay32.dll" into the QT debug folder.
I added the following to the project "pro" file:

```
LIBS += -LC:/OpenSSL-Win32/lib -lubsec
INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenSSL-Win32/include
```

I tried with and without the `setSslConfiguration` call.

But all this hasn't helped.

I tested SSL with the QT method:

```
if (QSslSocket::supportsSsl())
{
    qDebug() << "Supports SSL";
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "Does NOT Support SSL";
}
```

and that is saying "supported".

I am building the project in QT Creator, using MSVC2012 32bit settings.

Comment: i suggest to you connect QNetworkAcessManager::sslErrors signal to any slot and print error. so we can be sure that the error is in ssl